# Из-за чего ошибка (13)Permission denied: Couldn't read /var/www/SERVERUSER/.htaccess, closing connection или проделки Яндекс Бота?

Tags: apache, debian, веб-сервер

Периодически на сайты, размещенные на определенном сервере, заходит странный Яндекс Бот и в логи сыпятся такие ошибки:

[warn] [client 5.255.253.36] (13)Permission denied: Couldn't read /var/www/SERVERUSER/.htaccess, closing connection.

Вот только корень сайта имеет путь: /var/www/SERVERUSER/data/www/SITE.RU

На других серверах с другими сайтами таких ошибок нет, поэтому возникла мысль, что проблема в апаче на данном сервере. Что посоветуете друзья? Куда копать? Почему вообще идет обращение за .htaccess в родительскую папку пользователя SERVERUSER, а не сайта (в корневой папке сайта .htaccess имеется)?

Конфигурация virtualhost-а:

```
<Directory /var/www/*>
    Options +Includes -FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes Options=All,MultiViews
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/*/data/www/*/cgi-bin>
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>

<IfModule php5_module>
    php_admin_value open_basedir "."
</IfModule>
<IfModule php4_module>
    php_admin_value open_basedir "."
</IfModule>

Action php-cgi /php-bin/php

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/SERVERUSER1/data/www/SITE1.ru>
    Options -ExecCGI -Includes
</Directory>
<VirtualHost SERVERIP:80 >
    ServerName SITE1.ru
    AssignUserID SERVERUSER1 SERVERUSER1
    CustomLog /var/www/httpd-logs/SITE1.ru.access.log combined
    DocumentRoot /var/www/SERVERUSER1/data/www/SITE1.ru
    ErrorLog /var/www/httpd-logs/SITE1.ru.error.log
    ServerAdmin mail@SITE1.ru
    ServerAlias www.SITE1.ru
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost SERVERIP:80 >
    ServerName SITE2.ru
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    AssignUserID SERVERUSER2 SERVERUSER2
    CustomLog /var/www/httpd-logs/SITE2.ru.access.log combined
    DocumentRoot /var/www/SERVERUSER2/data/www/SITE2.ru
    ErrorLog /var/www/httpd-logs/SITE2.ru.error.log
    ServerAdmin mail@SITE2.ru
    ServerAlias www.SITE2.ru
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/SERVERUSER2/data:."
    php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f mail@SITE2.ru"
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/SERVERUSER2/data/mod-tmp"
    php_admin_value session.save_path "/var/www/SERVERUSER2/data/mod-tmp"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost SERVERIP:443 >
    SSLCertificateFile /var/www/httpd-cert/SERVERUSER2/SITE2.ru.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/httpd-cert/SERVERUSER2/SITE2.ru.key
    SSLEngine on
    ServerName SITE2.ru
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    AssignUserID SERVERUSER2 SERVERUSER2
    CustomLog /var/www/httpd-logs/SITE2.ru.access.log combined
    DocumentRoot /var/www/SERVERUSER2/data/www/SITE2.ru
    ErrorLog /var/www/httpd-logs/SITE2.ru.error.log
    ServerAdmin mail@SITE2.ru
    ServerAlias www.SITE2.ru
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/SERVERUSER2/data:."
    php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f mail@SITE2.ru"
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/SERVERUSER2/data/mod-tmp"
    php_admin_value session.save_path "/var/www/SERVERUSER2/data/mod-tmp"
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /var/www/*/data/>
    php_admin_flag engine off
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/SERVERUSER2/data/www/SITE2.ru>
    Options -ExecCGI -Includes
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/SERVERUSER2/data:."
    php_admin_flag engine on
</Directory>

NameVirtualHost *:443
NameVirtualHost SERVERIP:80
NameVirtualHost SERVERIP:443
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName www.example.com:443
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl.key/server.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: приведите, пожалуйста, конфигурацию *virtualhost*-а, добавив её в текст вопроса. отредактировать вопрос можно, нажав ссылку [edit].

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

у одного из ваших *virtualhost*-ов (самого первого) в конфигурации указано:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

одновременно для этого каталога разрешено отображение содержимого:

```
Options Indexes ...
```

попробуйте обратиться к вашему серверу, например, по его ip-адресу: `http://ip.ад.ре.с/`. вы увидите то же, что и поисковые «боты»: скорее всего, листинг содержимого каталога `/var/www`.

не знаю, нужен ли вам этот, самый первый *virtualhost*.

если нужен, мне кажется, имеет смысл сделать для него другой *docroot* и соответствующим образом подправить секцию `Directory /var/www/`, а секции `Directory /` и `Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin"`, равно как и директиву `scriptalias ...`, наверно, лучше вообще закомментировать.

---

помимо каких-нибудь проблем с конфигурацией *virtualhost*-а может быть и так, что какой-нибудь *symlink* в *docroot*-е сайта указывает на файл `/var/www/SERVERUSER/.htaccess` (не обязательно существующий), а следование *symlink*-ам разрешено в конфигурации этого *virtualhost*-а.

«обнаружить» такой *symlink* можно, например, так:

```
$ find /var/www/SERVERUSER/data/www -type l \
  -exec sh -c 'echo -n "{}: " ; readlink -f {}' \; | \
  grep /var/www/SERVERUSER/.htaccess
```

если файл найдётся, то вывод будет выглядеть так:

```
/путь/к/symlink-у: /var/www/SERVERUSER/.htaccess
```

Comment: symlink-и не обнаружил. Конфигурацию virtualhost-а добавил к первому сообщению.

Comment: я дополнил ответ.

Comment: По IP открывается SITE1.ru

Comment: да, вижу. ну, значит, обратитесь по непрописанному имени. например, так: `curl -H 'host: yandex.ru' http://адрес`, где в качестве адреса можете указать ip или любое из имён, которые резолвятся в ip-адрес вашего сервера. например, прямо на сервере можно указать `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Выполнил команду к доменам, некоторые отдают ошибку:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /
on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at yandex.ru Port 80</address>
</body></html>

Comment: В чём может быть причина?

Comment: @beckvlz, в наличии первого *virtualhost*-а, который я и предлагаю в ответе удалить.